# Extract graphs based on identifier and calculate network measures in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to separately analyze groups within a network. For example, the UK faculty data in the `igraphdata` package has some network data with group information on the node level.

```
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)
data("UKfaculty")

V(UKfaculty)$Group
```

I want to extract networks based on the 4 groups and run a few calculations on the extracted graph (density, average degree, diameter, clustering coefficient, etc.) and store this information based on the groups in a dataframe. I want to calculate the measures only based on the nodes within a group, not on the whole network level (e.g. calculating only centrality based on connections in group 1, not taking connections to other groups into account).

```
Group    density    diameter
    1          x           x
    2          x           x
    3          x           x
```

Any idea how to efficiently do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `induced_subgraph` to extract the subgraphs based on a `list` of vertices for every group.

```
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)

data("UKfaculty")
ig <- UKfaculty

# `list` of vertices for every group        
idx <- split(V(ig), V(ig)$Group)

# Create subgraphs based on the `list` of vertices
lst <- lapply(idx, function(v) induced_subgraph(ig, v))
```

It's then straight-forward to calculate any subgraph-specific metrics, e.g.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, function(ig)
    data.frame(
        Group = unique(V(ig)$Group),
        density = edge_density(ig),
        diameter = diameter(ig))))
#  Group   density diameter
#1     1 0.3001894       21
#2     2 0.3561254       12
#3     3 0.2807018       14
#4     4 1.0000000       12
```